# join->left_table with an SQL Select statement

Tags: database

Im adding a join via the query_alter hook.

```
  $join->left_table = '(SELECT * from blah)';
```

On the left table, instead of a table, I would like to put a select statement.
How do I do this?

Comment: If my answer solved this I'd appreciate it if you would "accept" it. If not, please comment clarifying what is still unclear and I'll do my best to help.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the documentation for [db_select](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) and [addJoin](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddJoin/7) it says the table:

> May be a string or another SelectQuery object. If a query object is passed, it will be used as a subselect.

This should be roughly right:

```
$subquery = db_select('blah');
$existing_query->addJoin('LEFT', $subquery...
```

I'm not sure if being in a query_alter hook or being a left join affect how this works, but it's a suggestion that should help you find the answer.

Comment: Small thing...`addJoin` returns the alias for the join rather than the query. Can be fixed by just removing `$query =` and continuing to refer to `$existing_query`